# How to check what URL your NSURLConnection is giving you a response from?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4

Before iOS5 I could test to see what URL I was getting a response from my code looked like this:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
    returnString = [[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    NSString * currentParseString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",connection];
    NSLog(@"Currently Parsing: %@",currentParseString);
}
```

my log would print out "`Currently Parsing: http://www.myinfo.com/parser....`"

Which I could then use to test and send into different IF statements. My problem now is, in iOS5 the `connection` is no longer printing as a URL, it is printing as a block of memory `<NSURLConnection: 0x6a6b6c0>` How could I get it to print out as a URL again so I dont have to rewrite my IF statements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did something like this :

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
   NSLog(@"%@",[connection currentRequest]);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Couldn't find `currentRequest` in the docs. make sure Apple is ok with it.

Comment: Ok, found `currentRequest` and `originalRequest` in the `NSURLConnection` header file. Looks like they are iOS 5 only. So go for it if that's ok for your app.

Answer (score 5):

When you put `%@` within a `NSString` format it will be replaced by `[object description]`. Apple must have changed what `[connection description]` returns. It's hard to rely on that in any case as it's not guaranteed to be in any particular format.

There are a number of ways you could change your implementation. Probably the quickest is to create a very simple subclass of `NSURLConnection` along the lines of:

```
// MyNSURLConnection.h
// code written assuming ARC
@interface MyNSURLConnection : NSURLConnection
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *requestURL;
@end
```

```
// MyNSURLConnection.m
// example override, you can override all the init/connection methods
- (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id)delegate startImmediately:(BOOL)startImmediately {
    self = [super initWithRequest:request delegate:delegate startImmediately:startImmediately;
    if (self) {
        self.requestURL = request.URL;
    }
    return self;
}
```

```
// in your MyNSURLConnectionDelegate controller
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(MyNSURLConnection *)connection {
    returnString = [[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
    NSString * currentParseString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",connection.requestURL];
    NSLog(@"Currently Parsing: %@",currentParseString);
    // rest of your code
}
```

Comment: +1 for a great answer XJones. I went with Maulik because his was a little more along the lines of what I was looking for. Although I'll keep this answer in mind for future projects. Thanks again!

Comment: no worries. the simplest solution that meets your requirements is the way to go.